# Difference between “if root == NULL” and “if !root”

Tags: c++

I was solving the first tree question on LeetCode [(Range Sum of BST)](https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst/submissions/) in which you have to implement a function that returns the sum of all nodes of a BST that have values between 2 given values L and R. My first solution was this:

```
int rangeSumBST(TreeNode* root, int L, int R) {
        if (root == NULL) return 0;
        else if (root -> val >= L && root-> val <=R) return root->val + rangeSumBST(root->left,L,R) + rangeSumBST(root->right,L,R);
        else if (root->val < L) return rangeSumBST(root->right, L, R);
        else return rangeSumBST(root->left, L, R);
    }
```

The runtime was 160 ms, which was indicated as "faster than 20% of submissions".

Then, I only changed `if (root == NULL) return 0;`  to `if (!root) return 0;`

And it made a huge difference; the runtime decreased to 100 ms (faster than 97% of all submissions).

Why did this happen?

Comment: There is no difference. Timing on that platform likely varies based on server load and shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: What does that question have to do with data structures or binary search trees? BTW: As a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, consider submitting your code for review at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You could try to run the same code several times. I bet they won't take the same time on every run.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm not sure this partial code would be good for codereview as-is. See also obligatory https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Yes, @AndrasDeak, that's good advise. I wanted to say that the shown code and probably the rest could benefit from a review, as even the above already contains at least two issues on first look.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt what are the issues?

Comment: One is "else after return", the other is the use of all uppercase names for things that aren't macros.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm still a beginner, I don't even know what a macro is.

Comment: Try putting "C++ macro" into the searchfield of your browser. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`!p`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/DPLKV7) and [`p == NULL`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3Cc15v) generate the exact same code with most compilers, this is unlikely to be the real reason behind the time difference. Actual reason is likely to be dependent on the load of server or some other external factor. Both `!p` and `p == nullptr` are widely used and equally valid/readable.